# Dynamically creating Bootstrap CSS alert messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically create alert messages using the jQuery plugin for Bootstrap CSS. I want to create and destroy alerts on certain events (e.g. AJAX success/error). Here's a non-working snippet of my code:

```
var alertVisible = false;
function fetchData() {
    function onDataReceived(stats) {
        if (alertVisible) {
            $(".alert-message").alert("close");
        }
        alertVisible = false;
        // Do stuff with data...
    }

    function onError() {
        $(".alert-message").alert();
        alertVisible = true;
    }

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: onDataReceived,
        error: onError,
        cache: false
    });
};
```

and here's the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="alert-message error fade in hide span16" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <p>Lost connection to server.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My first problem is that the alert is showed by default. I can kinda solve this by using the `hide` class. However, if you close an alert (by clicking on the close button) then creating new asserts no longer works (I guess the DOM element is gone). How are you supposed to use Bootstrap alerts?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This answer refers to Bootstrap 2.

When an alert is closed, it is removed from the DOM.

If you want to an alert to reappear later, make sure to *not* put `data-dismiss="alert"` in the close button as follows:

```
<div class="alert fade in" id="login-error" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
    Your error message goes here...
</div>
```

Then, bind the close button to simply hide the alert when it's pressed:

```
$('.alert .close').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

When you want the tooltip to reappear, simply show it.

```
$('#login-error').show();
```

Comment: BTW, `live` is dead from jQuery 1.9+; use `on` instead

Answer (score 25):

You could just dynamically add the DOM elements for the alert.

Javascript:

```
function addAlert(message) {
    $('#alerts').append(
        '<div class="alert">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">' +
            '&times;</button>' + message + '</div>');
}

function onError() {
    addAlert('Lost connection to server.');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="alerts"></div>
```

In the case of multiple alerts, this version will result in multiple alerts piling up that must be individually dismissed by the end user.  Depending on how many alerts you expect and how important it is for the user to see each one you might want to modify this to delete old alerts.

Also, with a little refactoring you can extend this to create warning, info, and success alerts in addition to this error alert.

Comment: An even better method would be to keep the entire alert text in html hidden via `.hide();` at `$(document).ready (function()`. When an alert is required, the block could be showed, and a single <div> block with info text inserted dynamically

Comment: I believe that won't work because the Bootstrap code will remove the alert from the DOM when the user closes it.

Comment: It would be good however to separate view from controller, which is an advantage of your suggestion.  One way to do this would be to store the alert in the HTML as you suggest and then copy it (using JQuery clone) and display it as a new block. You could modify the text for each alert if you want.  You could even use a JavaScript templating library, but it is probably only worth doing that if you are using one anyway for other reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I took Eamonn's answer and improved on it a bit, adding an optional `type` and `closeDelay`, so that you can, for example, add an alert of type `danger` that will close automatically after 5 seconds like so:

```
showAlert("Warning message", "danger", 5000);
```

To achieve that, add the following JavaScript function:

```
function showAlert(message, type, closeDelay) {

    var $cont = $("#alerts-container");

    if ($cont.length == 0) {
        // alerts-container does not exist, create it
        $cont = $('<div id="alerts-container">')
            .css({
                 position: "fixed"
                ,width: "50%"
                ,left: "25%"
                ,top: "10%"
            })
            .appendTo($("body"));
    }

    // default to alert-info; other options include success, warning, danger
    type = type || "info";    

    // create the alert div
    var alert = $('<div>')
        .addClass("fade in show alert alert-" + type)
        .append(
            $('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">')
            .append("&times;")
        )
        .append(message);

    // add the alert div to top of alerts-container, use append() to add to bottom
    $cont.prepend(alert);

    // if closeDelay was passed - set a timeout to close the alert
    if (closeDelay)
        window.setTimeout(function() { alert.alert("close") }, closeDelay);     
}
```

Comment: Good catch @SaiyajinGohan.  If you find the answer useful then please upvote it.  Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty good, but would be better as a jQuery plugin. You're querying for `#alerts-container` twice, I would cache that reference. Also, you could build the HTML a lot more legibly and easier to maintain using jQuery's built in functions, like `attr("type", "button")` and `addClass("alert")`, etc.

Upvoted, but it's kinda frowned upon to beg for votes.

Answer (score 5):

Best way that i know:

HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in" id="cert-error" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Этот файл не подходит!</h4>
    <p>Недопустимый тип файла! Выберите файл вида: *.cer, *.crt</p>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Take this action</a> <a class="btn" href="#">Or do this</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.alert .close').live("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});

function showAlert() {
    $(".alert").addClass("in");
    $("#cert-error").show();
}

function closeAlert() {    
    $("#cert-error").hide();
}
```

Now we can display notifications using showAlert() and hide them with closeAlert().

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct. On 'close' event of the alert whole Dom elements gets destroyed on which we have click. so we can not check the visibility property for that ids.

So my suggestion is 'do not use 'close' class or close event of the bootstrap-alerts.js.
Just get there classes for look and try to use traditional hide-show or some jquery tricks to get our task works.

Comment: I guess another option would be to insert the HTML in the DOM every time I want to show the alert.

Comment: Yes, This can be better option when we have to show different alert message each time..

Answer (score 1):

Change removeElement() function. Line 59 from bootstrap-alert.js:

Change:

```
.remove()
```

To:

```
.hide().css('opacity', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider an implementation of the Toastr library (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr by John Papa). Toastr gives you the alert functionality you require with native DOM event triggers or you can display a notification on PageLoad. It's worth investigating.